# indexOf() function returning undefined in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using a text field and calling a js function to check for decimalpoint.
there is a block in that js function as below:

```js
var nfGroups = newArray();
var decimalPos = inputObject.value.indexOf(nfGroups[numericFieldName][index].decimalPoint);
var selection = window.getSelection();
if(decimalPos != -1 && (selection.indexOf(nfGroups[numericFieldName][index].decimalPoint) == -1)
```

In the if statement for the second condition, in Safari, the value is undefined and hence a javascript error occurs. Can someone please help me with this.?
NumericFieldName is the name of the field used for entering price.

Comment: The current version of Safari is 8.0.7. Safari 5.1.7 is ancient. It doesn't get security updates any more. Stop supporting it. Remove it from any Windows machine it is installed on. Upgrade any Mac it is installed on.

Comment: Perhaps `window.getSelection` is undefined and hence the result of `indexOf` is undefined too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Quentin. Some of our applications run on the older version of Safari. Rewrite is in progress but for the time being, we need to use the 5.1.7 vesion.

Comment: Have you tried using the Polyfill from this page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply. I was trying some other possibilities and converting the var selection to string worked.
this is how i used:
if(decimalPos != -1 && (selection.toString().indexOf(nfGroups[numericFieldName][index].decimalPoint) == -1)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying some other possibilities and converting the var selection to string worked.

```js
this is how i used: if(decimalPos != -1 && (selection.toString().indexOf(nfGroups[numericFieldName][index].decimalPoint) == -1)
```

This worked.